# Proximity between numbers in an Interval

Tags: php, math, statistics

I have a set of (floating point) numbers between x = 1 and y = 9:

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

How can I compute a metric of the proximity, in the given interval, between number A and number B?

---

### What I've Tried

If the amplitude (`max - min`) of the above set is `9 - 1 = 8` I am able to compute the relative value of any number using the formula `(n - min) / (max - min)`, computing this for all values yields:

- `(1 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0`
- `(2 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.125`
- `(3 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.25`
- `(4 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.375`
- `(5 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.5`
- `(6 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.625`
- `(7 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.75`
- `(8 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 0.875`
- `(9 - 1) / (9 - 1) = 1`

Dividing the minimum relative value (between A and B) with the maximum relative value (also between A and B), seems to produce the kind of metric I'm looking for. Here are a few examples:

```
var_dump(min(0.875, 0.25) / max(0.875, 0.25));   // 0.286 between 8 and 3
var_dump(min(0.875, 0.375) / max(0.875, 0.375)); // 0.429 between 8 and 4
var_dump(min(0.875, 0.75) / max(0.875, 0.75));   // 0.857 between 8 and 7
var_dump(min(0.875, 0.875) / max(0.875, 0.875)); // 1 between 8 and 8
var_dump(min(0.25, 0.25) / max(0.25, 0.25));     // 1 between 3 and 3
```

---

### The Problem

Whenever the minimum value of the set comes into play, the result will always be `0`:

```
var_dump(min(0.875, 0) / max(0.875, 0));         // 0 between 8 and 1
var_dump(min(0.125, 0) / max(0.125, 0));         // 0 between 2 and 1
var_dump(min(0, 0) / max(0, 0));                 // 0 between 1 and 1 (ERR!)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What would be the problem with just taking the absolute value of the difference of the relative values?

Comment: which put another way would be `abs(A-B)/abs(x-y)` where `A` and `B` are the numbers you wish to compute the proximity of and `x` and `y` are the bounds of your predefined range?

Comment: What should be the proximity of 1 and 9? Should proximity of 7 and 8 be equal to proximity of 6 and 7?

Comment: @jedwards: That would give `0.015625` between `2` and `3`, and `0.09375` between `2` and `8`, and `0` if `A` and `B` are the same number (should be `1`).

Comment: @AlixAxel, I'll post my suggestion as an answer, I'm not sure its clear -- I'm getting values

Comment: how about `if(min($x,$y)==0){$p=1-max($x,$y);}` ?

Comment: @raina77ow: I'm not sure what the proximity between 1 and 9 should be, but `0` or something very close to it. Regarding the proximity between `6-7` and `7-8`, I'm not sure if they should be equal (but they should be close). The proximity between `4-5` and `5-6` should be equal (because they lie on the interval median).

Comment: @jedwards: Yeah, do that. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: Interesting. Didn't occur to me using conditions, let me try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was suggesting something like this:

```
<?php

function prox($a,$b)
{
    return(abs($a-$b) / abs(1-9));
}

printf("%f\n", prox(1,2)); // 0.125000 
printf("%f\n", prox(2,3)); // 0.125000
printf("%f\n", prox(1,1)); // 0.000000
printf("%f\n", prox(1,9)); // 1.000000
```

The proximity between 1 and 2 is the same as 2 and 3.  This seems to make sense.

The largest proximity you'll get is when the numbers you specify are the bounds of your predefined range.

The smallest proximity you'll get is when the numbers you specify are equal.

If you want the opposite to be true (which I suppose better reflects ***proximity***, you could do:

```
<?php

function prox($a,$b)
{
    return(1 - (abs($a-$b) / abs(1-9)));
}

printf("%f\n", prox(1,2));
printf("%f\n", prox(2,3));
printf("%f\n", prox(1,1));
printf("%f\n", prox(1,9));
```

Which would output:

```
0.875000
0.875000
1.000000
0.000000
```

Now, the same number produces 1 as you specified and the bounds produce 0 as they're the *least-proximate* pair of values.  Combinations like (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), etc. all produce the same value, as do combinations like (2,4), (3,5), (4,6), etc, etc.

Comment: Oh, makes total sense now.. And it's actually faster to compute. Nicely done, thanks! =)